# Any spare wheel/tire inside BMW i3?

Tags: tires, bmw, electric-vehicle, trunk, fix-a-flat

> - 1. Does BMW i3 has any spare wheel/tire in the car or in the trunk?
> - 2. If not, is there any recommended way to carry a spare wheel/tire inside the car?

See related discussions here: https://www.mybmwi3.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4080

[image]

Comment: So what is wrong with the information you link to? Do you expect a different answer? The idea is use the “glue”... or get a new tire.

Answer (score 1):

No, all you get a "Fix a flat" tyre sealant and small compressor.

The idea here is to save weight (longer battery range) and space.

BMW commissioned Bridgestone to make special tires just for this model. They are different from any other tire that Bridgestone makes (energy efficiency).

Even if you would decide to sacrifice your boot space for a spare wheel, bear in mind most countries have a law that spare wheel needs to be securely fitted or store away from the passenger compartment (boot fence e.g). Simple DIY to secure your spare wheel (if you can obtain one) might not cut it.

In my eye supplied tyre sealant (despite what mess it makes inside the tyre) is a good fix to get you to the nearest shop and have your tyre repaired.

Hope that helps.

Comment: A stone ripped a 1" gash in my tire wall, do you think that tire sealer you say is so good will work on that?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @Adam Cimler, not sure who downvoted -- I upvote instead +1. thanks!